# How to drag from an item from a list and drop to a editor field Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi everyone I'm trying to implement the following feature : I have a list, and I want to user be able to drag a row from this list and drop to a editor (Specific area in my screen ) and later, I'll represent this row with a shape like square or circle. For creating this I've decided to use [jsplumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/) and for this purpose I've written the followings [this is how my page seen currently](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7uy2r4azbx1g423/Screenshot%202015-09-10%2012.25.34.png?dl=0):

**html file**

```
 <template name="flowchart">
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">

                <div id="flowchart-left-panel">

                    <div id ="queries">
                        <h3>Queries</h3>
                        <select class="flowchart-select" id="query-list" size="20">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div id="filters">
                        <h3>Filters</h3>
                        <select class="flowchart-select" id="filter-list" size="10">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="span8">
                <h3>Flowchart Editor</h3>
                <div id="flowchart">

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</template>
```

**css file**

```
 #flowchart {
    background: url("/images/grid.gif");
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 1000px;
    transition: height 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s; /* Safari */

}

.flowchart-select{
    width:80%;
}

/*related with jsplumb*/
.item {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ddddff;
}

.title {
padding: 10px;
cursor: move;
}

.connect {
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
background-color: white;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

**js file**

```
Template.flowchart.rendered=function(){
    generateQueryList();
    generateFilterList();
}


function generateQueryList(){
    var selects = "";
    var i = 0;
    while(i<100){
        i++;
        selects += "<option value='" + i + "'> queryName:" +i  + "</option>";
    };

    $('#query-list').html(selects);
}

function generateFilterList(){
    var selects = "";
    var i = 0;
    while(i<30){
        i++;
        selects += "<option value='" + i + "'> filterName:" +i  + "</option>";
    };

    $('#filter-list').html(selects);
}
```